# VBA error 1004 in do until loop

Tags: excel, loops, vba

I'm pretty new to VBA, I've been succesfull before in programming loops, however, this time I can't seem to find the solution to make this code work.
The goal is to assemble data from one sheet (divided over 400+ seperate tables) to another sheet.

The program works without the outer loop, but when coding the loop around the other two loops I constantly get the error "run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

```
Dim x As String
Dim HStop As String
Dim y As String
Dim VStop As String
Dim z As Integer
Dim Row As Integer
Dim Column As Integer
Dim Counter As Integer

Sub Reform()

'1 maal te doen:

Row = 10
Column = 1
Counter = 6

'begin sub
Do

HStop = Worksheets("Find").Cells(2, 3).Value
VStop = Worksheets("Find").Cells(3, 3).Value

x = 1
y = 1

Do

Column = Column + 1
x = Worksheets("retour").Cells(Row, Column).Value


Loop Until x = HStop

'Checkpoint
Worksheets("Find").Cells(2, 12).Value = x

Do

Row = Row + 1
y = Worksheets("retour").Cells(Row + 7, 2).Value
Worksheets("Find").Cells(Counter, 12).Value = Worksheets("retour").Cells(Row, Column).Value
Counter = Counter + 1

Loop Until y = VStop

'Checkpoint
Worksheets("Find").Cells(3, 14).Value = y
Worksheets("Find").Cells(2, 14).Value = Row
Worksheets("Find").Cells(3, 14).Value = Column

z = z + 1

Loop Until z = 10

End Sub
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Which line does it crash on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not sure how this code will help you to get desired result, however the error occurs because in the following peice of code

```
Do
    HStop = Worksheets("Find").Cells(2, 3).Value
    VStop = Worksheets("Find").Cells(3, 3).Value
    x = 1
    y = 1
    Do
        Column = Column + 1
        x = Worksheets("retour").Cells(Row, Column).Value
    Loop Until x = HStop
    'Checkpoint
```

`HStop` is assigned a value, then in the loop you are assigning another value to `x` and looping till `x = HStop`. In `Do` loop you are also incrementing the value of `Column`. In case, `x` is not equal to `HStop` and `Column` value reaches `16385` i.e. one more than the last column of the sheet, it throws runtime error while assigning

```
x = Worksheets("retour").Cells(Row, 16385).Value
```

Comment: That did it! The value assigned to HStop was missing in the 7th table of data. so like you stated the Column value reached 16385. thanks for the quick help, would have taken me forever to figure it out myself.